# Haskell data type parametrized with random generator data type

Tags: haskell

How can I parametrize a data type with a random generator data type?
I tried this:

```
data DataType g = Data (RandomGen g)
```

But I get

```
Predicate `RandomGen g' used as a type
In the type `RandomGen g'
In the definition of data constructor `Data'
In the data declaration for `DataType'
Failed, modules loaded: GameState.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RandomGen` is a **type class**, not type. Use `StdGen` if that fits you. And it isn't parametrized by anything, so you need just `data DataType = Data StdGen`.

Comment: Then it is less polymorphic.  Perhaps he wants `data DataType  a = DataConstr a`.  That is, the constraints should be placed on the functions using `DataType` and not on the type declaration.